# Why is my Mongodb aggregation pipeline update working in compass, but not working in my node driver

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

### Problem:

I need to only update one document in a nested array of subdocuments. My previous query was updating all matching documents which is no good *Example Below*. So I decided to use aggregation so that I could add a limit stage so that I could only update one item, but I cannot get the update to happen through node and I am not even getting errors.

#### Old Query/Update:

**This query updates all documents that match the shape of userId: `"empty"` I need it to only update the first match**

```js
           const query = await db.collection('events').updateOne({
                _id: new ObjectId(eventId),
                createdBy: new ObjectId(createdBy),
                "weights.weight": weight
            },
                {
                    $set: {
                        "weights.$.spotsAvailable.$[el2]": {
                            "name": applicantName,
                            "userId": new ObjectId(applicantId)
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    arrayFilters: [
                        {
                            "el2.userId": "empty"
                        }
                    ]
                })
```

**I have tested the aggregation in the MongoDB compass aggregation builder and it works fine.
But in the actual node code no luck**

---

I have tried:

1. Pluging in variables without the `new ObjectId` syntax
2. Plugin in variables with the `new ObjectId` syntax
3. Using the exact same hardcoded values that I got from copying the aggregation code from compass for the node driver

### Example document

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6398c34ca67dbe3286452f23"
  },
  "name": "test",
  "createdBy": {
    "$oid": "636c1778f1d09191074f9690"
  },
  "description": "testing",
  "date": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1645488000000"
    }
  },
  "location": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      0,
      0
    ]
  },
  "weights": [
    {
      "spotsAvailable": [
        {
          "name": "empty",
          "userId": "empty"
        },
        {
          "name": "empty",
          "userId": "empty"
        },
        {
          "name": "empty",
          "userId": "empty"
        }
      ],
      "weight": 12
    },
    {
      "spotsAvailable": [
        {
          "name": "empty",
          "userId": "empty"
        },
        {
          "name": "empty",
          "userId": "empty"
        }
      ],
      "weight": 15
    }
  ],
  "eventApplicants": [
    {
      "userId": {
        "$oid": "636c1778f1d09191074f9690"
      },
      "name": "Wayne Wrestler",
      "weight": 15
    }
  ]
}
```

### Code:

```js
const acceptOrRemoveApplicant = async (eventId: ObjectId, createdBy: ObjectId, applicantId: ObjectId, applicantName: string, boolean: boolean, weight: number): Promise<boolean | undefined> => {
    console.log({ eventId, createdBy, applicantId, applicantName, boolean, weight })
    if (boolean == true) {
        try {
            /*
         * Requires the MongoDB Node.js Driver
         * https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native
         */

            const agg = [
                {
                    '$match': {
                        '_id': new ObjectId('6398c34ca67dbe3286452f23'),
                        'createdBy': new ObjectId('636c1778f1d09191074f9690')
                    }
                }, {
                    '$unwind': {
                        'path': '$weights'
                    }
                }, {
                    '$unwind': {
                        'path': '$weights.spotsAvailable'
                    }
                }, {
                    '$match': {
                        'weights.spotsAvailable.name': 'empty',
                        'weights.weight': 15
                    }
                }, {
                    '$limit': 1
                }, {
                    '$set': {
                        'weights.spotsAvailable.name': 'Wayen',
                        'weights.spotsAvailable.userId': '123456'
                    }
                }
            ]

            const client = await clientPromise;
            const db = client.db();
            const query = db.collection('events').aggregate(agg);


            // const query = await db.collection('events').updateOne({
            //     _id: new ObjectId(eventId),
            //     createdBy: new ObjectId(createdBy),
            //     "weights.weight": weight
            // },
            //     {
            //         $set: {
            //             "weights.$.spotsAvailable.$[el2]": {
            //                 "name": applicantName,
            //                 "userId": new ObjectId(applicantId)
            //             }
            //         }
            //     },
            //     {
            //         arrayFilters: [
            //             {
            //                 "el2.userId": "empty"
            //             }
            //         ]
            //     })

            if (query) {
                console.log("we queried")
                console.log({ query })
                return true
            } else {
                throw new Error("User not added to event")
            }

        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
        }
```

Comment: Can you please provide some sample input documents.

Comment: I updated my question sorry that I didn't already have that there. And thank you for taking the time to try and answer my question